# how to compare two images in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new on here and even with Xcode. I'm trying to create a simple iOS App to play with my kids at school (as they are with Autism).

I want to create an App that shows up random 2 images and the kid should choose from 2 buttons if they're equal or not. Also with 4 images is ok, and he should choose which are the same.

At the moment I'm stuck after the design.. 
Is here someone who can give me some hints/examples how to solve this?

Thanks, Radu!

Comment: Hey, you dont actually need to change the images right? Lets say, you have a grid of four images. If you want the user to pick two identical images, I would just load two grids with the same image. and keep some type of array in the back end, if the elements match up, they are equal. Let me know if you need help implementing this.

Comment: You don't need images comparison.
For example, you have three images A, B, C, and four buttons 1, 2, 3, 4
Then you place:
-image A on button 2
-image B on button 1 and 3
-image C on button 4

User choose buttons 1 and 2, you don't need to compare images to say that they not equal

Comment: @TheAppMentor. Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's something like that! Can you give me some example to start from? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just made a sample app for you. Here is the snippet.

**Step 1:**
I just make my UI like this.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Then in code segment i just wrote like this.
[image]
[image]

Hope you will understand.